# Extending paragraph indentation in a list

Tags: support, list

I am typesetting some explanations that work in steps, so that a bulleted or numbered list is appropriate. But the explanations may extend on several paragraphs and I would like to keep the indentation at the same level. Is this possible?

Example.

1. This is the first item.

Item one continues and I want this paragraph aligned on the previous.

2. This is the second item.

---

**Update**:

The solution is by inserting a space before the paragraph.

1. This is the first item.

   Item one continues and I made this paragraph aligned on the previous.
2. This is the second item.

Comment: Just add a space. It's explained in the help in the editor

Comment: @Cai: simple as that ! Thanks (I didn't find this info in the help.)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#advanced-lists